# Can I use a Kinect to identify objects?

Tags: kinect, object-detection

Pylons decide a path. I want the Kinect to detect pylons so that I can make my robot to stay within the path. Is Kinect capable of object detection and is there any tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinect itself is just a device which will get you some image data and depth values (via [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/) or the [upcoming SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/)). So you're looking for a library (or combination of several ones) which can do this based on the data. Not sure there is something which provides a direct solution, but it seems a combination with [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) has been successful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRBozGoa69s